# Can I parse relative times with JodaTime?

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime, relative-date

I'd love to be able to parse relative strings like `now` and `yesterday` and get JodaTime DateTimes. Is it possible? DateTimeFormat.forPattern and doesn't seem to support English relative times and I don't know of any other parsing options in JodaTime.

I should add that I'm using [scala-time](http://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time) but can easily drop down to the actual JodaTime classes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you illustrate an example of what you would like to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write either a separate library, or a DateTimeParser. DateTimeParser is the interface used internally by Joda-Time to parse text. Anyone can implement it and plug it directly into the Joda-Time parsing system using DateTimeFormatterBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see here - "now", "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow". Is that about it? :-)

JodaTime won't parse them for you but it should be trivial enough to write your own function (or enum) to do so; you can even throw in stuff like "day after tomorrow" if you feel like it.

"Now" seems to be the only value for which `DateTime` would be appropriate, though - all others look more like `LocalDate` (or, possibly, `DateMidnight`) to me.